# Не работает скрипт для автозаполнения

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

есть скрипт (script), он может принимать несколько аргументов (help, history, work), и я хочу, чтобы для него работало автозаполнение(например вместо полного написания 'script help' или 'script history' написать 'script hi', нажать на TAB, и строка автоматически заполнилась), нашёл в интернете вот такой способ:

```
_my_command(){ #объявляем функцию, которую будем привязывать к анализу
    
    COMPREPLY=() #пока что мы не знаем, что предложить пользователю, поэтому создадим пустой список.
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}" #получаем текущий вводимый аргумент
    subcommands_1="work history help" #массив подкоманд первого уровня

    if [[ ${COMP_CWORD} == 1 ]] ; then #если вводится первый аргумент, то попробуем его дополнить
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${subcommands_1}" -- ${cur}) ) #some magic
        return 0 #COMPREPLY заполнен, можно выходить
    fi
    }

complete -F _my_command script
```

но после запуска у меня он не работает. в чём может быть проблема? есть ли более простая альтернатива этому?
версия ядра:Debian 6.0.10-2kali1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `нашёл в интернете вот такой способ` если ссылаетесь на что-то то желательно и ссылку на это давать чтобы меньше возникало вопросов. Я так понимаю речь идёт про эту статью на хабре - [Использование bash completion в командной строке, собственных скриптах и приложениях. Часть 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/115886/). Проверил у себя, работает. Закиньте вышеприведённый вами код в конец файла `$HOME/.bashrc`, после откройте **новый** терминал и там уже вводите то что нужно, тока не забудте табать не один а **два** раза.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но ничего не изменилось: нажимаю tab 1 раз - выводится список файлов в текущей папке, 2 раза - эти файлы выбираются и подставляются после script. И разве есть разница (кроме того, что запуск через консоль одноразовый) запускать файл через консоль или через bashrc? Статья эта. Учту, что нужно оставлять ссылки в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Я заметил, что такой метод у меня вообще не работает. Например в /usr/share/bash-completion/completions есть много файлов с применением этих методов, но автодополнение не работает для программ к которым они написаны.

Comment: @Freekby а вы точно пробуете авто-дополнение в оболочке `bash` ? может там у вас sh, zsh или еще что-то ? чтобы проверить какая запущена оболочка шел у вас в текущем терминале выполните команду `echo $0`

Comment: `нажимаю tab 1 раз - выводится список файлов в текущей папке` - по умолчанию в чистом баше для этого нужно нажать 2 раза. `И разве есть разница запускать файл через консоль или через bashrc?` - просто в данном случае это самый простой способ, если заработает так то уже можно пробовать и всё остальное.

Comment: после долгих поисков проблемы я так ничего и не нашёл, но она как-то решилась сама собой, после того как я перезагрузил компьтер.